# Increment field on row if exists, else insert new row

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

Imagine a table storing tags for questions, like the tags that go on stack overflow questions.

I want to track how many questions have a tag.

I made this table

```
create table tag (name text primary key, questions counter);
```

Now I want to add a tag to the table, but if it  already exists it shouldn't be added, it should increase the `questions` of the existing tag by `1`.

I think it will look something like

```
update tag set questions = questions + 1 where name = ? if exists
insert tag (name, questions) values (?, 1) if not exists
```

But the above gives me the error:

```
Conditional updates are not supported on counter tables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates in cassandra works as `upsert`.

If same primary key exists it will be overwritten else it will create new.

```
update tag set questions = questions + 1 where name = ?
```

Only this will take care of requirements